# Drive not appearing in Optimise Drives (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

Running Windows 10 with two 16GB pen drives (mapped to `F:` and `P:`) and a larger 4TB WD external disk (mapped to `W:`). All drives work correctly, appear in Windows Explorer, Disk Management, you can navigate to them in the command prompt, etc.

But the external hard drive is not appearing in `Optimise Drives` (right-click any drive > Properties > Tools > Optimise and defragment drive). The two pen drives do appear.

Now open a command prompt and type `defrag W: /a`. The `defrag` utility instantly returns with no analysis or error. Type `defrag P: /a` and some analysis stats are displayed. Type `defrag M: /a` and the following error is displayed:

```
The given volume path is invalid. (0x89000001)
```

The external hard drive `W:` appears to be recognised, but ignored, by the defragmentation utilities built into Windows.

Why? And how do you defragment a drive that Windows won't show?

#### Update

From the command-prompt I ran "chkdsk W: /f" and after completion (took about 3 minutes), the extrernal drive appeared in `Optimise Drives`. Still curious to know if there is more going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple listed reasons a drive might not show up in the Optimize menu (dfrgui.exe):

> You can't defragment specific file system volumes or drives,
> including:
>
> - Volumes locked by the file system.
> - Volumes the file system marked as dirty, indicating possible corruption. You must run chkdsk before you can defragment this volume
>   or drive. You can determine if a volume is dirty by using the command
>   `fsutil dirty query C:` .
> - Network drives.
> - CD-ROMs.
> - File system volumes that aren't NTFS, ReFS, Fat or Fat32.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/defrag

In your case, it's most likely the drive was in dirty state (which usually shows a different error in `defrag`), or some other problem with the filesystem fixed by `chkdsk`. Some external or USB HDDs have a kind of "sleep" mode for power saving you can look into too, though it's less common.

If it happens again, you can try to unmount/remount the drive, or reboot windows with the drive connected